# py2exe or pyinstaller fail to include jaraco.util

Tags: python, py2exe, importerror, pyinstaller

I have a small python script for irc which needs `jaraco.util` to function. Requirement is to release it as binary on windows so I've tried with **py2exe** and **pyinstaller**.

I am using **WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4**

I have some experience with `py2exe` from previous projects, I tried the 'includes' option as well but without any success.
The error is pretty much standard:

```
ImportError: No module named jaraco
```

Or `jaraco.util` etc. if I try to include it via `setup.py` for the `py2exe` build.

```
      'includes': [
                   'jaraco.util',
                   'irc',
                   'ConfigParser',
          ],
```

Normally it should auto-detect the dependencies but if I leave it without the include it will build the exe but fail to execute with a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "irc\client.pyc", line 67, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jaraco.util.itertools
```

In `winpython` site-packages I have:

```
jaraco
jaraco.timing-1.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth
jaraco.timing-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
jaraco.util-10.6-py2.7-nspkg.pth
jaraco.util-10.6-py2.7.egg-info
```

I also tried to reinstall `jaraco.util` and to copy it manually after the build but it will still not work.

I've searched on-line for a solution for at least a couple of hours but to no avail. so I'm trying here maybe you guys have run into similar issues (or maybe I'm doing something wrong...)

Thank you

Comment: The [FAQ](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ#How_does_py2exe_decide_which_modules_you_need.3F) recommends analyzing the output of `python -m py2exe.mf -ddddd irc\client.py`? Can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `jaraco` was installed via `easy_install jaraco.util`, thus creating python eggs, which aren't supported by `py2exe`, as detailed by its [FAQ](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs).

Try specifying the flag `--always-unzip` as an option to `easy_install`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked (and I recall seeing somebody mention unzip while searching on this but I guess i was to tired last night and didn't pay to much attention to it)